# Stripe Payment Intents and charge.succeeded webhook sometimes not firing

Tags: stripe-payments, webhooks

We create PaymentIntents (with `capture_method=manual` in case that matters) in our iOS/Android apps when the user places an order.

We send the order to the connected venue once the `charge.succeeded` webhook fires. If this doesn't happen within a couple of minutes, we expired the placed order on our side.

So interestingly 2 out of 10 times we don't get this webhook to fire.

Im wondering if it's actually wise to listen to this webhook in order to decide if we send the order to the connected account's venue or not or if there is a better way to determine that the payment will actually work once we try to capture it.

Answer (score 4):

Webhooks are the recommended way for getting a payment intent's status, but you can also use the API to get its status.

A quote from the Stripe [docs](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents/verifying-status):

> It is technically possible to use polling instead of webhooks to
>   monitor for changes caused by asynchronous operations—repeatedly
>   retrieving a PaymentIntent so that you can check its status—but this
>   is markedly less reliable and may pose challenges if used at scale.
>   Stripe enforces rate limiting on API requests, so exercise caution
>   should you decide to use polling.

In your case, I'd recommend waiting for the webhook and then after  a few minutes, call either the [PaymentIntents API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents) or the [Charges API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges) if you haven't received the webhook yet.

Comment: That sounds like a pretty good workaround. Doing a manual call to the api before we actually would expire the order and determine the status.

Thanks for the input, I‘ll give that a try.

Comment: This source here https://stripe.com/docs/rate-limits sai's that the stripe api allows 100 read operations per second and 100 write operations per second. I don't know if this means 100 altogether or 100 by each user. If its 100 for each user then polling would definitely be reliable. However if it's 100 per second for everyone using the api altogether then it being unreliable makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

There's likely something else going on here, so I'd suggest you [reach out to Stripe](https://support.stripe.com/contact/email) - webhooks should fire all the time, and it's a really really rare occurrence that they wouldn't.

Comment: I did, we basically found that the webhook is firing but something on our end with processing the event fails sometime. It's like we don't even get the call from the webhook. We're currently deploying a version which will get us more insights + includes the workaround mentioned by Delena.